# Trying to whitelist node module in jest config

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm hoping this is just a simple mistake on my part, but here's what I'm doing. I have a react native project, and I'm importing via url another react native project that's going to become a common library. Because it's early days, I've not transpiled the code in this other project. I'm able to import components from there and run the webapp, but I'm having problems with the tests (jest).
I dug around a bit and found that you're supposed to whitelist non-transpiled node modules in your jest config, like so:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(react-native|my-module))/"
],
```

However, this has made no difference to the error I encounter when running the tests:

```
FAIL  src/App.test.js
```

● Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

/path/to/my/workspace/node_modules/my-module/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

  1 | import {combineReducers} from "redux";
  2 | import {reducer as formReducer} from "redux-form";
> 3 | import partialForm from "my-module/src/reducers/form";
    | ^
  4 | import progress from "my-module/src/reducers/progress";
  5 | // import theme from "my-module/src/reducers/theme";
  6 | 

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/reducers/index.js:3:1)
```

Can anyone point out my (probably) basic error?

Answer (score 0):

Overcame this problem with some modifications to babel config in package.json:

```
"babel": {
     "presets": [
-      "react-native"
+      "react-native-dotenv"
     ],
     "env": {
-      "test-web": {
+      "test:web": {
+        "presets": [
+          "react-native",
+          "es2015"
+        ],
         "plugins": [
           [
-            "react-native-web"
+            "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
+            "transform-strict-mode",
+            "syntax-class-properties",
+            "transform-class-properties",
+            "transform-async-to-generator",
+            "transform-flow-strip-types",
+            "transform-react-jsx",
+            "react-native-web/babel"
           ]
         ]
       },
-      "development-web": {
+      "development:web": {
+        "presets": [
+          "react-native",
+          "es2015"
+        ],
         "plugins": [
-          [
-            "react-native-web"
-          ]
+          "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
+          "transform-strict-mode",
+          "syntax-class-properties",
+          "transform-class-properties",
+          "transform-async-to-generator",
+          "transform-flow-strip-types",
+          "transform-react-jsx",
+          "react-native-web/babel"
         ]
       },
-      "production-web": {
+      "production:web": {
+        "presets": [
+          "react-native",
+          "es2015"
+        ],
         "plugins": [
-          [
-            "react-native-web"
-          ]
+          "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
+          "transform-strict-mode",
+          "syntax-class-properties",
+          "transform-class-properties",
+          "transform-async-to-generator",
+          "transform-flow-strip-types",
+          "transform-react-jsx",
+          "react-native-web/babel"
         ]
       },
-      "test": {
-        "plugins": []
+      "test:native": {
+        "presets": [
+          "react-native-stage-0"
+        ],
+        "plugins": [
+          "syntax-class-properties"
+        ]
       },
-      "development": {
-        "plugins": []
+      "development:native": {
+        "presets": [
+          "react-native-stage-0"
+        ],
+        "plugins": [
+          "syntax-class-properties"
+        ]
       },
-      "production": {
-        "plugins": []
+      "production:native": {
+        "presets": [
+          "react-native-stage-0"
+        ],
+        "plugins": [
+          "syntax-class-properties"
+        ]
       }
     }
   },
```